# How to find all points along a route between two points on google map using python

Tags: python, google-maps, gis, offline

I need to find latitudes and longitudes of all points that lie along the route between two points (start point and end point, both represented as lat-long pair) in the google map. I have 1 million start points and the corresponding 1 million end points. So, basically I would have 1 million routes and I need to find all points that lie along each of these 1 million routes, separately. I do not want to call google javascript api, because there is a restriction on the no of calls that one can make per day. Also, this will not scale. Can anyone please suggest, how can I do it using python and some offline api/tool for google map?

Comment: Between the path connecting any two points, there are infinitely many other points. Is there some specific spatial resolution you're going for?

Comment: As far as I know, If I use google map javascript api to draw a route between a start point and an end point, it renders the polyline which passes through some intermediate points (that lie on the route). I just need those points so that I can use those points to write some custom function, but, without calling the online api service that google map provides. The reason for this is, I need to get this done for 1 million routes, where each route comprises a different set of start point and an end point. For this to be faster and scalable, I need offline processing.

Answer (score 2):

You say you represent a *route* as start/end point, you have to consider that for each pair of start and end points you can have more than one route (depending on the mode of travel, etc.).

This is why you need routing. If you don't want to use Google's directions API you can check [OpenStreetMap's routing APIs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) or [roll your own router](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Developers) using existing libraries and engines on OSM data.

Similar question: [Calculating shortest path on maps (Google Maps, Openstreetmaps, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314782/calculating-shortest-path-on-maps-google-maps-openstreetmaps-etc)